# Transitive DI using cake pattern

Tags: scala, cake-pattern

I'm trying to do dependency injection using the cake pattern like so:

```
trait FooComponent {
  val foo: Foo

  trait Foo;
}

trait AlsoNeedsFoo {
  this: FooComponent =>
}

trait RequiresFoo {
  this: FooComponent =>

  val a = new AlsoNeedsFoo with FooComponent{
    val foo: this.type#Foo = RequiresFoo.this.foo
  }

}
```

but the compiler complains that the `RequiresFoo.this.type#Foo` doesn't conform to the expected type `this.type#Foo`.

So the question: is it possible to create a `AlsoNeedsFoo` object inside `RequiresFoo` so that dependency injection works properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With cake pattern you should not instantiate other components, but extends them.

In your case you if you need functionality of `AlsoNeedsFoo` you should write something like this:

```
this: FooComponent with AlsoNeedsFoo with ... =>
```

And put all together on top level:

```
val app = MyImpl extends FooComponent with AlsoNeedsFoo with RequiresFoo with ...
```

Comment: But that means that it's not possible to create multiple instances of `AlsoNeedsFoo` (inside `RequiresFoo`). Is that correct?